# How to install nodejs 6.7.0 on Ubuntu 14

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I have found some guides (for ex. [Install latest nodejs version in ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974535/install-latest-nodejs-version-in-ubuntu-14-04)) how to install updated version of NodeJS, also followed the official one that says to use

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

which is the same thing as in the SO guide above.
However, the version of node I get is 6.3.1 but I want the latest 6.7.0. I have installed 6.7.0 on OSX via brew but don't know how to get it on Ubuntu. Is there any way to do it, using APT preferably?

Comment: When down voting, can you at least specify why...? It's like saying "I think it's wrong" with "because ..." missing

Comment: You can use nvm (Node version manager ) and install any version

Comment: But via APT it's cleaner. Latest stable is 6.6.0. Why it doesn't give me that?

Comment: i do't use that but nvm will provide flexibility to use any version at any time .you just put simple command and switch in to any version node

Answer (score 0):

I have done this way:-

```
sudo npm install n -g
sudo n 6.7.0
```

Alternatively for **latest stable version** you can do this:-

```
sudo n stable
```

And For **latest version**

```
sudo n latest
```