# Unable to fix the versioning with node & npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm working with ubuntu 14.04 LTS version. I have nodejs 0.10.x version installed on my PC, now i bought nodejs v6.9.4, respect to this latest version i updated the $PATH variable, now

> $node -v
>   Giving v6.9.4, where as internally npm and node not identifying these latest version, it is saying when i try to update any of the packages

```
wanted: {"node":">=4.0.0"} (current: {"node":"0.12.7","npm":"2.11.3"})
```

How to update these versions globally?

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: a simple google search query can solve this

Comment: I tried the solutions whatever i got from the google since 2 days.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install latest nodejs version in ubuntu 14.04](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974535/install-latest-nodejs-version-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Don't think that people who are posting questions are fools, luckily most of them are trying and at last they came to post here..   I found that possible duplicate in my research, But my concern is different.

Answer (score 0):

nvm install v6.9.1

Solved my problem.

Thanks,

Answer (score -2):

if you are struggling with nvm like I was. You want to start by removing your package installer. It's probably the one causing problems.

On your terminal
sudo apt autoremove
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-error-code-1

Step 2: https://joshtronic.com/2022/04/24/how-to-install-nodejs-18-on-ubuntu-2004-lts/

sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

Step 3: sudo apt install -y curl

Step 4: curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash -
Step 5: sudo apt install -y nodejs

Step 6: node --version

Should be good to go