# NodeJs: globally installed module not found

Tags: node.js, npm

I set the prefix of npm to d:\npm and installed various modules globally, also I added d:\npm to the Path environment variable and created a NODE_PATH variable pointing to d:\npm\node_modules.

The installed Files are all in den expected directory and stuff like `protractor --version` works.

However when I require a globally installed module(with `require('jasmine-trx-reporter')`) I get an error that it cannot be found.
On a different machine where I have all the dependency's as dev-dependency installed the same project works with no problems so it has to be some linking issues.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I import global modules in Node? I get "Error: Cannot find module <module>"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970793/how-do-i-import-global-modules-in-node-i-get-error-cannot-find-module-module)

Answer (score 0):

This will not work:

```
require(jasmine-trx-reporter)
```

You need to use:

```
require('jasmine-trx-reporter');
```

with quotes. Maybe it was just a typo in the question.

You shouldn't rely on modules being installed globally. It's best to add them to dependencies (or devDependencies) in package.json, use `npm install` to install them and be sure what you are requiring.

Relying on the packages being installed globally is asking for trouble.

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed a typo, I will correct it.
However I need it to install the modules globally because it gets deployed on an Team Foundation Server where the project files will be always purged on build and I dont want to install the modules every time.