# why is the Nodejs module is not installed globally on debian 8?

Tags: node.js, linux, debian, node-modules

I had installed the NodeJS like this:

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs`

And updated npm:

`npm install npm@latest -g`

Then installed the express module

`npm install express -g`

At the end i've created a file test.js in which wrote `require("express")`. Then tried to execute the file by comand `node test`, but NodeJS said what he cant to find the express module:

`Error: Cannot find module 'express'`

Comment: Did you install with sudo? Sometimes you have to do that when installing globally

Comment: possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970793/how-do-i-import-global-modules-in-node-i-get-error-cannot-find-module-module

Comment: @selten98 no, i'm not. i didn't install the sudo utility

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://unix.stackexchange.com/