# Can node.js ignore a local node_modules directory and only use global modules?

Tags: node.js

Can node.js be configured to only use a globally-installed modules and ignore a local node_modules directory?

For our [node.js app](https://github.com/mdn/kumascript) (currently node.js 8.10.0), we build a Docker image where the required modules are installed globally, in a `/node_modules` folder, with the environment set to `NODE_PATH=/node_modules`. This works for production deployment.

For local development, we run the same Docker image, but mount the local development files at `/app`. This allows any locally changed files to be used by the image.

This works, until a developer runs `npm install` on their host system, and creates a `node_modules` directory. This is mounted at `/app/node_modules`. `node` examines this folder on startup, and [starts complaining](https://github.com/mdn/kumascript/issues/666) about missing binaries:

```
kumascript_1     | ## There is an issue with `node-fibers` ##
kumascript_1     | `/app/node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-57/fibers.node` is missing.
kumascript_1     | 
kumascript_1     | Try running this to fix the issue: /usr/local/bin/node /app/node_modules/fibers/build
kumascript_1     | /app/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:20
kumascript_1     |  throw new Error('Missing binary. See message above.');
kumascript_1     |  ^
kumascript_1     | 
kumascript_1     | Error: Missing binary. See message above.
kumascript_1     |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:20:8)
kumascript_1     |     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
kumascript_1     |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
kumascript_1     |     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
kumascript_1     |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
kumascript_1     |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
kumascript_1     |     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
kumascript_1     |     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
kumascript_1     |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/lib/kumascript/templates.js:11:13)
kumascript_1     |     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
```

If there was a way to tell `node` to ignore `/app/node_modules`, then a developer can do what they want with `npm install` on the host system, and the Docker container would continue running as expected.

Comment: [this may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970793/how-do-i-import-global-modules-in-node-i-get-error-cannot-find-module-module)