# Can you prevent node.js from installing packages locally? (Use global packages)

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, require

I've been working on a lot of different node.js projects. All of them have their own `package.json` file with their own needed packages. Every time I run `node <mainfile>.js`, **npm** installs all the packages to the project directory. Like so: `C:/Users/me/Projects/<project-name>/node_modules`.

This isn't a very big problem, but is there a way to make **npm** use/install to the *global* packages? Like in `C:/Users/me/node_modules`?
One of the advantages I could see this having is less storage being taken up, although it isn't a huge advantage.

I would assume that if it is possible, it would require you to add/modify something in the `package.json` file.

While looking into answers for this question, I've seen people saying that you should avoid installing packages globally. Can you also explain why this is a bad practice andy why I should avoid it?

Comment: Do you want to know how to install packages globally?

Comment: No i know how to do that. (Adding the `-g` argument to `npm install <package>`)

Comment: You need to know why you shouldn't add packages globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Package Globally

NPM installs global packages into //local/lib/node_modules folder.

Apply -g in the install command to install package globally.

```
npm install -g express
```

To answer your other question

> The obvious short answer is that your project depends on them. If your
> project depends on a package, it should be documented in package.json
> so that you can guarantee that it is installed when someone types npm
> install. Otherwise, you’ll need to add extra steps in your README file
> to inform anyone else who clones your project that they need to
> install each of your global dependencies as well
>
> Finally, even if someone installs the correct version of Browserify
> for your project, they may be working on a different project that
> requires a different version of that same tool, which would cause
> conflicts. Several of your own projects might even use different
> versions of Browserify because you updated it when you started a new
> project and didn’t go back to make sure that earlier projects were
> updated to work with the new version. These conflicts can be avoided.

*You can only have one version installed globally. This causes problems if you have different projects that rely on different versions of a package.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? @Noah Gerard

Comment: This still doesn't answer my question -  is there a way to make npm use/install to the global packages?

Comment: @NoahGerard You can link the global packages this way npm link <global-package> https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link this the link on how to use the global packages locally

Comment: Oh ok. I'll look into that

Answer (score 1):

## Why not to install all packages globally

It's not really you shouldn't install a package globally it's more knowing what packages to install globally. The packages to install globally are ones that your project/application does not depend on.

## How to identify a package that my project depends on

A package that your project is depended on is a package that your application could not run without like `axios` or `express` (an `express` API could not run without express installed or a web page that makes API requests with `axios` cant make those requests without `axios`) but something like `http-server` or `minify` is not needed to run the application so it can be installed globally.

## Why is it important to have locally installed packages

It's important/good practice because if you are working with a group of developers or someone gets your work from Github they can just run `npm install` and get all the packages with out having to find all the packages them selfs.

## How can I remove the node modules folder

You could technically globally install every package but I would sudjest not to. Node and many other developers know this is an issue that they have created a solution for in deno "the node killer".

I would recommend not installing all packages globally and if the node modules folder really annoys you try deno it fixes a lot of things that node developers hate.

Comment: This still doesn't answer my question -  is there a way to make npm use/install to the global packages?

Comment: Have a look at the link below (the accepted answer) this is probably what you want but he also subjects to not do this if you plan to deploy your application. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970793/how-do-i-import-global-modules-in-node-i-get-error-cannot-find-module-module