# Node looks for global packages in the wrong folder

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I have a few npm packages installed globally `npm install <package> -g`.

Before switching environments (dev machine -> server) I could just do `import {method} from 'package'` and node would import from global.

I've tried settings node path `export NODE_PATH=$(npm root --quiet -g)` as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43504699/13040656) answer, but it doesn't work.

How can I tell node to import from the global folder instead trying to import a lcoal package? I'm getting `Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'ws'` so I assume that is what's happening.

The `NODE_PATH` is pointing at the right folder where the packages are installed, but the error shows that it tries to import from a different path.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Before switching environments"

Comment: My machine I use for development -> server

Comment: first check if the package has been successfully installed run  'npm list -g', then check if you have the same node version installed on both machines

Comment: All packages are showing up

Comment: try clearing Node.js module cache by running 'npm cache clean --force' and then restart the terminal

Comment: @Ibrahim.B Didn't work