# where can I find bower_components?

Tags: html, node.js, git, bower

When I download a git project and I run it shows some files are in bower_components folder.
I cannot the find the bower_components folder in my project but there is a bower.json files.Can I convert this bower.json to bower_components folder.

Comment: Run `bower install`.

Comment: How to run 'bower install' ? From where?

Comment: Type `bower install` at the command line, after installing it with `npm install -g bower` if necessary. The README of the repo is likely to contain instructions on this and other necessary setup steps.

Comment: I installed 'npm install -g bower'. now where should i type bower install?  When I type it in the root directory it says     'bower' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run "bower install" in the folder where bower.json in.
Because bower will search bower.json in current folder and install all in the bower.json.

Answer (score 1):

Cd to Project directory and then do bower install. This command will create the bower_components folder in the project directory and add all the dependencies to the bower_components folder.