# Installing express generator error

Tags: node.js, express, generator

Everytime I try to run the command npm install -g express-generator I receive the following errors. Do you have a solution to this problem?

[image: image of errors I receive]

Comment: run `npm -v` what is the output?

Comment: This is the result of running npm - v http://ambitiousbranding.com/error2.jpg

Comment: your `npm` binary is not in the path.

Comment: how did you install `node` ?

Comment: I went to the website and downloaded the package. Am I in the right folder ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8 try this

Comment: OK Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

Though Your Problem seems to your system's error  because as your screen shot shows : I've observed following:

1. You've Altered Your NodeJs Installation Directory(knowingly / Unknowingly)
2. Packages are stored here : "C:\Users\YOUR_AC_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm"

Remedies :

1. First Uninstall Node.js Completely From System
2. Delete Residue Folders left behind
3. Install a Fresh copy of Node.js
4. Add Path to Environment + System Variable as Following :

   C:\Program Files\nodejs

   C:\Users\YOUR_AC_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm
5. After That Install Express Generator Globally

Hope It Helps :)