# After installing serverless on Windows 10, I can't run "serverless" at the command prompt

Tags: node.js, lambda, serverless-framework

I installed NodeJS, which seems to work fine.  Running npm worked fine and I could install packages. Then I ran

```
npm install serverless -g
```

which also ran fine.  But when I try to run:

```
serverless
```

at the windows command prompt, I get an error about the command not being found.

```
'serverless' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I've included the answer is below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fixing npm path in Windows 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8)

Comment: @DrakaSan My npm was working just fine.  It's the things npm was installing that weren't working.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The issue for me was that I was missing the following directory in my Windows PATH env variable:

```
%AppData%\npm
```

Once I added that, I could run serverless, sls, etc.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I added the path, but still serverless commands are unrecognized in my machine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like you found a solution.  Glad it worked out!

Comment: After that, just restart Windows !!
Thanks for the help. I spent 2 hours

Comment: I think you just need to restart the console, not the whole computer.

Answer (score 7):

This is probably a stupid answer, but might help someone i hope.

I was facing the same problem, even after adding the path. I found that my AppData folder was hidden somehow, making it available fixed the issue for me.
(also after making the changes don't forget to open a new CMD :D )

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, when i run the Command Prompt as Administrator it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have a stupid answer, too: I had used nvm to change my node version last week. I had changed back to the same version in the meantime, but you still have to install serverless again then.

Answer (score 1):

I just run below command and its working fine for me:

1. This command is for installing serverless-offline which helps to run serverless application on local system `npm install serverless-offline --save-dev`

and then,

2. This command is for solving 'serverless' is not recognized as an internal...  issue

`npm install -g serverless`