# Make an outbound phone call using nexmo

Tags: javascript, node.js, vonage

Good day guys i can't understand what is in here
[Make an outbound phone call using nexmo](https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2017/01/12/make-outbound-text-speech-phone-call-node-js-dr/).

I did follow the instruction here and type it in my cmd

so first i did this:

> npm install nexmo-cli -g

then after i installed it i tried to create and application id:

> nexmo app:create "My Voice App" http://example.com/answer http://example.com/event --keyfile private.key

but it says on my cmd that:

> 'nexmo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I really can't follow what's on blog can you please help me understand it guys. What i want here to make an outbound call using nexmo

Comment: What is the output when running `npm install -g nexmo-cli`?

Comment: '--nexmo-cli@0.3.10' i guess it is successful

Comment: What OS are you using? What is the contents of your $PATH?

Comment: @aaronbassett I'm using Windows 8 . And what do you mean by my $PATH?

Comment: [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Comment: I don't understand sir.

Comment: In your terminal run `echo %path%` and add the output here. You may want to redact any personal information in directory names

Comment: if you echo it sir well obviously it will just copy what you write

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147912/discussion-between-aaronbassett-and-theginxx009).

Comment: you can use https://dashboard.nexmo.com/voice/create-application to create application, it will generate the private.key file and application id to use them for creating outbound calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the folder your node modules are installed in is not on your Windows path. To find this folder run

```
npm config get prefix
```

Ensure that this folder is within your Windows path, you can view this by running

```
echo %path%
```

If it is missing from your path see these answers: [fixing npm path in Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8)

Comment: is this the answer?

Comment: Yes. Without updating your `%path%` you will need to use the full path to the Nexmo CLI each time, such as `node C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nexmo-cli\lib\bin.js`

Comment: i did it like this ```C:\Users\{MyUsername}\AppData\Roaming\npm``` then hit enter after that i tried this ```nexmo app:create "My Voice App" http://example.com/answer http://example.com/event --keyfile private.key```
now it is recognize but it says ```could not read credentials. Please run nexmo setup```