# Angular: ng is not recognized as a command

Tags: javascript, angular

C:\Users\Vivek Ghanchi>ng
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I have  installed  angular CLI but it is showing me the ng is not recognized  is there any solution

Comment: Have you installed Angular CLI globally? Is it included in the PATH variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fixing npm path in Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8)

Answer (score 2):

You should install angular cli by enter the following command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 2):

Use;
Environment Tables -> System variables -> Path:

```
C:\Users\*'Your User'*\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

not

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm**\node_modules\angular-cli\bin**
```

Be aware that the path should point to YOUR USER work directory if You are not working on Administrator account.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it few days ago, after having the same problem with other global modules, by adding to:

Environment Tables -> System variables -> Path:

C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin

Note that it must not have any spaces after ;
That turned out to be my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [link](https://cli.angular.io/) to know about angular CLI. After installing Angular CLI you can able to see workable ***ng*** command.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, I uninstalled `node js` and then reinstalled it. Now if you run `node --version`, it will show current version of node, Its `14.16.1` in my case. Now run command `npm install @angular/cli`. It will install angular CLI. One can also run `npm --version` before angular cli installation for being sure that `npm` is working. Might be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

try `ng --help` to see if your command parameter is in the list, and word is correct. For example, `ng -v` is not support in new version, use `ng v` instead.