# Node Isn't Recognized In Command Prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

I have node installed however in my main terminal I cant access it. I can run the "Node.js command prompt" and it will work fine but shouldn't I be able to run node in the terminal?
[image]

Comment: check if its added in your system's environment path variable.

Comment: to do so, check this link here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27864253/5088262

Comment: The path is set successfully or not. please, check it before.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `node` parent directory to the system `$PATH` variable.