# Node installed but not installed

Tags: node.js, npm, command-prompt

I'm trying to download and install node.js through the npm.

I've downloaded node.js from the website and can open it as seen here:

[image]

When I try to confirm its installation via the windows command prompt, I get this:
[image]

Trying to initialize the npm doesn't work either:
[image]

This is my first time trying to get into back-end dev and i don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: I would guess that you need to set the path to node.js and npm so the executables can be automatically found.  Where did you install them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8-and-10/32159233  this should help you

Comment: Yup. Thanks. All good now.

Comment: Now I'm getting another error when trying to install node-sass.