# Can't find sam binary after installing aws-sam-local with npm

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I am trying to install `aws-sam-local` for Windows 10 using README.md in [official GitHub repository](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-local).

However after npm installation is completed I can't find `sam` binary. Also in installation directory `bin` folder looks empty:

```
PS ...\node_modules\aws-sam-local> ls bin


    Directory: ...\node_modules\aws-sam-local\bin


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         5/2/2018   1:22 PM          11357 LICENSE
-a----         5/2/2018   1:22 PM             92 NOTICE
```

Unfortunately my PATH variable has nothing related to the installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found it under `node_modules\aws-sam-local\node_modules\.bin`.
It's strange that there are 2 binaries available in different subfolders:

```
.\AppData\Roaming\npm\sam.exe
.\node_modules\aws-sam-local\node_modules\.bin\sam.exe
```

The first one is 0.2.8 and second one is 0.2.11.

This fixed the PATH variable issue for me:
[Fixing npm path in Windows 8 and 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8-and-10)