# npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file in visual studio

Tags: node.js, angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54ePo.png)
I am not able build the angular project in visual studio using **ng serve**,but I am able to do it using **node.js command prompt**
please give me solutions for this one

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8-and-10/32159233

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixing npm path in Windows 8 and 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8-and-10)

Comment: please check your node version with this command in cmd: `node -v` & `npm -v`

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the solutions suggested in the links which are posted in the comments, you can also try the below command to update the PATH,

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME_OR_LOGIN\AppData\Roaming\npm;
```

Once executed, try re-running your `ng serve` command again.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Install Angular cli globally using this command.

```
$ npm install -g @angular/cli
```

the `-g` switch installs angular cli(or any npm package globally on your system).

Comment: C:\Users\snadarge>$ npm install -g @angular/cli
'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.                                                                                                    ->I tried but not working

Comment: It seems you don’t have node and npm installed on your system. Follow instruction and install them first using below link: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows

Comment: I have already installed it, problem is I am not able to use it CMD, but I can use it in nodeCommand

Comment: If you want to use the command in cmd you should add npm bin directory into your windows environment variables. I will put the link of how to do that

Comment: https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-install-and-use-node-js-and-npm-mac-and-windows/