# Windows power shell: vue --version 'is not recognized'

Tags: powershell, vue.js, vue-cli-3

I am trying to learn vuejs.

1. Run Power shell as an Administrator.
2. Installed it globally:

   C:\Windows\system32> npm install -g @vue/cli
3. This message appeared:

npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.5: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead
    C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue -> C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli\bin\vue.js

```
> protobufjs@6.8.8 postinstall C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\protobufjs
> node scripts/postinstall


> nodemon@1.18.10 postinstall C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @vue/cli@3.5.0
added 680 packages from 509 contributors in 124.261s
```

4. Then I want to check it's version using 'vue --version':

   C:\Windows\system32> vue --version

vue : The term 'vue' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ vue --version
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (vue:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I have tried Uninstalled and Reinstall. still not working.

- my version of node : v10.15.3
- my version of npm : 6.4.1

What should I do?

Comment: Make sure you have an Environmental Path set to the correct location. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8-and-10  First, figure out where node is installing the global modules - browse to `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin ` ..do you see a Vue package in there? Or does it live in: `C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules ` ...Is that path part of your Environmental Path Variables? What happens when you do `node -v` and `npm -v` ?

Comment: if i do command like node -v or --version also npm -v or --version it works fine.

Comment: interesting... I would check that other thread - something is up with your Environmental Path variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out if your prefix is set correctly to your AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/ (etc..)

Type `npm config get prefix` and see if it's there.

If doesn't, that may be causing your -g packages to be installed somewhere else. Do `npm config set prefix C:/users/your_user/AppData/Roaming/npm` and then try installing some package. That might solve any of unrecognized dependecies to occur.

Answer (score 1):

try to reinstalll everything with node 8.11.0 as it's recommanded by [@vue/cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html)

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was the package name change:

> Warning regarding Previous Versions
>
> The package name changed from **vue-cli** to **@vue/cli**. If you have the
> previous vue-cli (1.x or 2.x) package installed globally, you need to
> uninstall it first with `npm uninstall vue-cli -g` **or** `yarn global remove vue-cli`.

soure: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to add following in Path System variable and restart command prompt.

```
C:\Users\{YourAccount}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin
```

once added issue `yarn -v` and you will see the version output.

Once yarn installed issue below command to install vue-cli

```
yarn global add @vue/cli @vue/cli-service-global
vue --version will show you the version
```