# 'vue' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli-3

everything was installed correctly. but whenever I try to create project, it says "'vue' is not recognized as an internal or external command". I installed and re-installed but didn't work. npm was also added to environmental variable path.

```
C:\Users\touha\Desktop>npm list -g --depth=0
C:\Users\touha\.npm-packages
`-- @vue/cli@3.8.2


C:\Users\touha\Desktop>vue ui
'vue' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\touha\Desktop>
```

Comment: try uninstalling it and try npm install -g @vue/cli again, this should suffice to use the vue command

Comment: tried several times. also uninstalled and reinstalled node js. didn't work

Comment: Sure looks like you didn't install the vue cli globally.

Comment: Did you follow these steps? https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html

Comment: I installed vue using `npm install -g @vue/cli` as mentioned in the documentation

Comment: `.npm-packages/bin` or whatever it's called is not on your [PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8-and-10)

Comment: yup that worked! @birdspider.
actually i added `C:\Users\USERNAME\.npm-packages` on PATH variables.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Locate *vue.cmd* and add its location to your PATH**

It is added to package manager(npm or yarn) installation. So you may find it at following locations

YARN

> C:\Users{YourAccount}\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin

NPM

> C:\Users{YourAccount}\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: Link how to add it to the `PATH` on `Windows`: https://www.technig.com/solve-vue-command-not-found-windows/

Answer (score 13):

just open PowerShell and run: `npm install -g @vue/cli`

Comment: It helped me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Addition: If setting the path variable and reinstalling @vue/cli does not work, using the node.js command prompt instead might solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

what worked for me: \

1. Open a PowerShell
2. `npm install vue` \
3. `npm install -g @vue/cli` \
4. `C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue.cmd create {NAME}`

**Note:** If you have installed vue using the above command, then use the last command to specify the `vue.cmd` to PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

It seems vue isn't been installed globally for some reasons.
This is the step I followed to solve mine:

Firstly, create your desired project folder (say "Vue Project"). This is where you want to create a vue project.

Then create a "node_modules" folder in the Vue Project folder

Then go to your system npm folder C:\Users{YourAccount}\AppData\Roaming\npm

You will see three different "vue" files. Copy them and paste in the Vue Project Folder you created.

Go back to C:\Users{YourAccount}\AppData\Roaming\npm and enter the node_modules folder. You'll see a "@vue" folder. Copy this, and paste it in the node_modules folder you created in the Vue Project Folder.

You can now head back to the CLI and create your project using "vue create my-vue-project" where my-vue-project is your desired vue project name.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way it worked for me
go to the location of your yarn or npm mine is **C:\Users\TED\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin** for Yarn
**C:\Users\TED\AppData\Local\Npm\bin** for Npm users
TED will be replaced by your user name
then copy and add it to your system environment variable

**Note** in case you don't find AppData make sure you have view hidden file checked

Answer (score 1):

I am using Yarn to install @vue/cli.

The way I solve it is via the following steps

1. Locate your global installed vue.cmd location
2. Add the vue.cmd directory into System variable Env. For myself, the path is `C:\Users{MyAccount}\AppData\Local\Yarn\.bin`

Answer (score 1):

1. Run command prompt as administrator
2. Run `setx /M path "%path%;%appdata%\npm`
3. Restart the command prompt
4. Now create the Vue project

Answer (score 0):

if you got this error most probably chance package not installed completely
check-in C:\Users\dev\AppData\Roaming\npm
if you had not found the package under this folder then re-run your command