# Trouble installing Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, npm-install

I am trying to install Vuejs but getting error message:

What am I doing wrong and how can I get it installed?

Reinstalled Node.js and updated npm.

```
C:\Users\chris>npm install -g @vue/cli
C:\.node_modules\global\vue -> C:\.node_modules\global\node_modules\@vue\cli\bin\vue.js
C:\.node_modules\global
`-- @vue/cli@3.11.0

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

C:\Users\chris>vue --version
'vue' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: You're probably missing bin path, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8-and-10

Answer (score 2):

I think you are probably missing the path bin by doing the following:

1. Search environment variables at your start menu's search box.
2. Click it then go to Environment Variables.
3. Click PATH, click Edit
4. Click New and try to copy and paste this: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin

You will have to restart any currently-opened command prompts before it will take effect.

Also have a look at this thread they solved a similar issue.
[Fixing npm path in Windows 8 and 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8-and-10)