# Error when trying to build APK with cordova | :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED

Tags: android, cordova, build, compiler-errors

- I've set all the needed requirements for the cordova build.
- I've set all the needed "Enivrement Variables".

Installed: Java JDK, Android JDK, Android target and Gradle.

***Problem:***

When I enter "cordova build android", everything starts to compile fine until it comes to "Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED"

I'm new to cordova. I've tryed some solutions from the internet like:

- Putting the images into an "assets" folder.
- Updating "Gradle".
- Checked the "config.xml" file for syntax error.

This is the error get after the build starts:
[image: This is the error get after the build starts:]

Comment: Are there multiple `config.xml` files which need to be merged for the release? If yes, do they contain the same keys?

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann No there is only one config.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution by fixing the npm path in Windows.

There is already an solution to this problem:

[Fixing npm path in Windows 8 and 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8-and-10)