# how to set path for node.js

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I installed node.js in my windows7 64 bit. but when i am trying to run the command

```
npm -v
```

its giving me an error 
`CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g`
is not recognised as internal or external command

i tried setting nodejs path in system variables . Following is the statement i added

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

i restarted the system too, stil its not working
how do i solve this?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixing npm path in Windows 8 and 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8-and-10)

Comment: @DusayantaPrasad I tried the things mentioned in the post but it does not work for me. If you see the error i posted , in the path after nodejs there is \\(doible forward slash). How do i correct that?

Comment: Open up a command prompt in this path **C:\Program Files\nodejs** . Run the given commands and paste the output here in your post- `npm get prefix` and `npm get userconfig`

Comment: @DusayantaPrasad i have updated the question . "comand line result" is a screenshot of the cmd. Please click on it

Comment: Please post the content of **.npmrc** file too. The path is there in your image.