# Not able to install apisauce in react-native project

Tags: react-native, apisauce

I tried to install using the following code:

```
npm i apisauce --save
```

However, I got these errors:

> npm WARN react-navigation-stack@2.8.2 requires a peer of
> react-navigation@^4.1.1 but none is installed. You must install peer
> dependencies yourself.
>
> npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall rename npm ERR! path
> F:\DoneWithIt\node_modules\follow-redirects\node_modules\debug npm
> ERR! dest
> F:\DoneWithIt\node_modules\follow-redirects\node_modules.debug.DELETE
> npm ERR! errno -4058 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or
> directory, rename
> 'F:\DoneWithIt\node_modules\follow-redirects\node_modules\debug' ->
> 'F:\DoneWithIt\node_modules\follow-redirects\node_modules.debug.DELETE'
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Ravi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-08-01T13_33_29_249Z-debug.log

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck on this same issue today and I think I fixed it just now. I followed the suggestions of uninstalling nodejs (and the node_modules folder if that doesn't also get automatically removed with it), making sure that your nodejs folder is in the environment variables path.

The stackoverflow thread I referenced is: [Fixing npm path in Windows 8 and 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8-and-10)

Comment: Deleting node_modules and npm installing worked for me. I did not need to uninstall node.