# NPM won't install dependencies via Git Bash

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I'm trying to install a new dependency on NPM called Nodemon, every time I try to GitBash doesn't respond.
**package.json** reads this;

```
 "name": "server",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
   "start": "node index.js"
 },
 "keywords": [],
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
   "express": "^4.17.1",
   "morgan": "^1.10.0"
 },
 "devDependencies": {},
 "description": ""
}
```

Here's what GitBash shows.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cover the bases:

1. Check if you have node and npm installed [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/)
   `$ node -v`
   `$ npm -v`
2. Make sure your bash is in the correct directory
   `$ pwd`
   `$ ls`
3. Install locally [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)
   `npm install nodemon`
4. Install Globally
   `npm install -g nodemon`

Comment: I have done steps 1, and 2. Steps 3 and 4 is where it won't install ANY dependancies.

Comment: If you are on a windows machine perhaps your environment variables did not update? https://stackoverflow.com/a/27864253/4718533

Comment: I am on a windows machine, and I tried updating the PATH in my Environment Variables. Still no luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting my router and restarting the router seemed to fix it as well as installing packages from scratch. It looks like when I was installing the dependency originally, I closed GitBash prematurely and it caused a heap of problems, including this one.