# ServerlessError: Serverless plugin "sls" not found

Tags: serverless-framework, aws-serverless, aws-sdk-nodejs

i'm trying to use serverless for the first time and although I think I have followed the docs etc I'm getting a weird error.

I have installed serverless and a few functions:

```
npm install -g serverless
npm install -g serverless-plugin-optimize
```

```
sls invoke local -f auth-handler -s local
Serverless: To ensure safe major version upgrades ensure "frameworkVersion" setting in service configuration (recommended setup: "frameworkVersion: ^2.1.1")


  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  ServerlessError: Serverless plugin "sls" not found. Make sure it's installed and listed in the "plugins" section of your serverless config file.
      at C:\Users\cw\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:155:17
...
```

As you can see, I'm invoking sls and its running (I've exported `SLS_DEBUG=* sls` to get some debug)

sls reports this as the environment:

```
Your Environment Information 
---------------------------
     Operating System:          win32
     Node Version:              12.18.4
     Framework Version:         2.1.1
     Plugin Version:            4.0.4
     SDK Version:               2.3.2
     Components Version:        3.1.3
```

my serverless.yml is:

```
service: serverless-optimize-example
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.18

package:
  individually: true

custom:
  enable_optimize:
    local: false

plugins:
  - sls
  - serverless-plugin-optimize
  - serverless-offline

functions:
  auth-handler:
    handler: src/index.handler
    optimize: ${self:custom.enable_optimize.${opt:stage,'dev'}, 'true'}
    events:
      - http:
          path: /func1
          method: get
```

What do I have to do to install sls, even though it looks like it is installed?

**UPDATE**
I got it working, thanks @David Webster. It was this SO:

[Fixing npm path in Windows 8 and 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8-and-10)

That finally solved it. For anybody else. There were 2 directories that needed to be added to my path:

```
%APPDATA%\npm
<path to nodejs>\node_modules\npm\bin e.g. C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin
```

Comment: npm install -g serverless worked for me

Comment: Cheers. Yeah, I've done that. Should have stated that in my question. I've event completely restarted my laptop so that anything that was added would get picked up by the shell. Anybody else got any other ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a windows issue https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3393

Answer (score 0):

So, further to the path issue I've added in my update, there is one *MASSIVE* gotcha. I didnt pot it originally. One of the documents I read said to add:

```
plugins:
 - sls
 ...
```

Turns out this was cuasing the issue. My plugins now looks like:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-optimize
  - serverless-offline
```