# npm install command not regular work how i fix that problem?

Tags: powershell, vue.js

npm install command not regular work, this is the error.[enter image description here][1]

npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- npm install
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsp1k.png
  ```

Comment: Either you haven't installed nmp, or it's not in your path. have you installed node.js? https://npm.community/t/npm-install-error/4907/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like [npm isn't part of your path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27864253/15299500). For Windows 10, you can hit Start, start typing "environment variables" until it has a result, click "Environment Variables..." in the ensuing System Properties window, then edit the "Path" variable to include your NPM installation.