# npm Error When creating vue project using Vue-CLI

Tags: vue.js, npm

I am new to Vue. and searched everywhere for the correct answer. But no luck. Please Help me on this.

I can't create a new vue project.
at the first I ran `npm install -g @vue/cli`

and after that `vue create vue-animated-ui`

But it gives an error,

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.22.0\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\execa\index.js:347
                throw err;
                ^

Error: Command failed: npm --version
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


    at makeError (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.22.0\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at Function.module.exports.sync (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.22.0\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\execa\index.js:338:15)
    at new PackageManager (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.22.0\node_modules\@vue\cli\lib\util\ProjectPackageManager.js:126:42)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.22.0\node_modules\@vue\cli\lib\util\getVersions.js:6:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
```

npm version `6.14.6` and vue cli version `@vue/cli 4.5.13`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: npm is clearly not in your Windows `PATH` variable. See [the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8-and-10) for how to solve it. Then retry in a new terminal window (=with the reloaded environment)

Comment: @Tyblitz thank you so much. After i add path to Environment variable.it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! base the file path looks like you are using NVM control the node version.

- So I think this issue is not `vue/cli` issue. it's an `nvm` issue.

- And base on the error message it's npm v can not execute.
- I suggest you first check in this path
  `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.22.0\node_modules\`

- Do you have the `npm` folder like this: [image]
- If not it means when you use `nvm use 10.22.0` it does not install the npm.
- So you can install manually

  - this is the node npm version: [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/)
  - node v10.22.0 should use npm v6.14.6
  - go to [npm](https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/) download the 6.14.6 version.
  - unzip it to your path `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.22.0\node_modules\` and rename it to `npm`
- then try `npm -v` if you got version. means it's work. it'll also work for vue/cli

Comment: Yes nvm controlls to node version. But once I add nodejs path to Environmental variable. It worked. But Thank you.

Comment: Ahhh. usually, it's the npm's issue. nice, it worked for you.