# npx-create-react-app my-app command ERROR in Vs Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

```
npx : The term 'npx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ npx create-react-app my-app
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npx:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

have you install the Node.Js?

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

if so, it's probably a "PATH environment variable" issue

[Fixing npm path in Windows 8 and 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8-and-10)

Comment: yes I've installed node.js, and there isn't any Path environment variable issue. I tried installing node.js 32bit for windows, and its working fine now .

Answer (score 0):

try this code.
`npm install -g create-react-app-offline`

Answer (score -1):

You should install npx globally, try this:

```
npm i -g npx
```

On mac/linux use sudo:

```
sudo npm i -g npx
```

Answer (score -1):

Install node.js, after that then restart your VS code.

Answer (score -1):

After installation , restart your vscode

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).