# why is npm install -g @angular/cli not working?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, cmd

[image]

Trying to install angular/cli in cmd, node.js verson 8.1.2

Comment: Did you install nodejs? https://nodejs.org/en/ if it already install set a path to nodejs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8-and-10

Comment: @MaheshKS Yes I have version 8.1.2

Comment: In your CMD run  command node -v if it it generate an error then maybe the nodejs path is not set in windows or please restart ( close and reopen) cmd and try again to install angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the Nodejs "PATH" variable. You can see how it should look in the picture.

[image]

If you open the "CMD" window again later, you can successfully complete the installation process.