# Why do I have an error "'vue' is not recognized as an internal or external command" in VS code?

Tags: vue.js

So I started working with vue and I installed vue cli in visual studio code with the following command:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

But when I try to create a vue app with `vue create ...` command, it says the following:

```
"'vue' is not recognized as an internal or external command"
```

I searched in google and added npm in the PATH, and also node js, so I don't know what can be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You're probably missing the bin path.

Have a look at ['vue' is not recognized as an internal or external command on windows #347](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/347#issuecomment-279157468). It includes multiple possible answers!

**Possible fix:** (copied from [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32159233/16758153))

get the path from npm:

```
npm config get prefix
```

and just as a future reference, this is the path I added in Windows 10:

```
C:\Users\{yourName}\AppData\Roaming\npm
```