React Native package download issue
[I am getting this error. I have no issue working on react.js. The node is correctly installed as i can get the versions]
I am not also able to find the path for npm using which or whereis
[I tried reinstalling still the error exists.]
[I tried clearing the npm cache but it didn't execute.]

Make sure npm is in your Windows PATH. After that, open a new cmd terminal (PowerShell seems to have some issues with this) and try this command.

How do you check if it is in the windows path??

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8-and-10. Also try using a different terminal like cmd or Windows Terminal.
