# I Installed npm But Cannot Install DocPad

Tags: docpad

Obviously I need to download DocPad (file(s)) before I can do an npm install, but it simply isn't clear to me what to download, etc.  I know the file(s) I need are on [**GitHub**](https://github.com/docpad/docpad), but I don't have the background to understand what I'm looking at.  Can you give me, or point me to, a "Download DocPad for Dummies" instructions?  Thank you.

Comment: Did you have a look at their install guide? http://docpad.org/docs/install

Comment: Thanx, @ezig.  However the "npm install -g npm; npm install -g docpad@6.78" is what had me scratching my head. I'm on Windows XP, and I understand this is a command line prompt (I'm an old programmer from when computer programs did not run from GUIs). I've already installed npm, and can run it, but is "docpad@6.78" a file?  Where do I find it?  Where do I put it so that npm can find it?

Comment: You put it in npm global directory (that's why you install it with -g), more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages . Also, in console you will be able to call docpad commands, like `docpad server`, but I'm not sure if it will work on Windows, never tried

Answer (score 0):

To extend on @sindis's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31949702/i-installed-npm-but-cannot-install-docpad#comment51988545_31949702)

When you install Node, you will also install [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com), which serves as the node package manager.

npm allows you to [install packages globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally) using the `-g` flag, which installs a package that has been published to npm (such as DocPad) to wherever the npm global installation directory is, and make DocPad's command line tools available to you.

So by installing DocPad with `npm install -g docpad@6.78` (`6.78` is the version of DocPad that the command above wishes to install) we will install DocPad to the global npm installation directory, which makes the command line tool `docpad` available for your use.

I've updated the [DocPad installation guide](http://docpad.org/docs/install/) to be a bit clearer about this, suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The installation of DocPad is all controlled by NPM. So once that is installed, all you should need to do to install DocPad is run the npm command, as others have said, `npm install docpad -g`.

Now, the gotcha in windows is that you might need to execute this command with elevated rights - ie Administrator. Windows doesn't like you installing programs in its root program directory.