# How to kill a process that restarts? (Forever)

Tags: node.js, terminal, ports, forever

I think I accidentally installed Foreverjs somewhere and started it. Every time I kill this process another one takes its place[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vneb8.png)

I have no idea where forever might be (or if thats actually whats causing it) because I install it locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it restarts itself it means there is a parent process monitoring. Find the parent process and kill it first `ps -o ppid= -p PID`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Where does npm install packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages) and  [npm folders](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders) documentation

> Local install (default): puts stuff in ./node_modules of the current
> package root.
>
> Global install (with -g): puts stuff in **/usr/local** or
> **wherever node is installed**.

run `which forever` to get the path where its installed and uninstall it with

- `forever stopall`
- `npm uninstall forever` if its globally installed
  add `-g`

Comment: Hey thanks! As I mentioned, it is a local install so I cannot use forever in the command-line like that. The issue was that I had many many different projects scattered everywhere with their own node_modules folders, not that I didn't know that npm installs things into the node_modules folder

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had run the same script on PM2 on both a root user and of my new privileged user. The root user kept restarting the process with PM2 every time i killed it and its parent.
So I did this

```
sudo su
pm2 status //to check pm2 processes
pm2 delete process_name //to delete the process
exit 
pm2 start "yarn start" --name process_name
```

Hope this helps save someone else's time