# Maximum call stack size exceeded on npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to run `npm install`, this is output from console:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.8.0-27-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8

npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

and this is content of `npm-debug.log`:

```
113791 verbose stack RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
113791 verbose stack     at Object.color (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/console-control-strings/index.js:115:32)
113791 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.log._format (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/log.js:252:51)
113791 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/log.js:138:24)
113791 verbose stack     at emitThree (events.js:116:13)
113791 verbose stack     at emit (events.js:194:7)
113791 verbose stack     at .<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/tracker-group.js:23:18)
113791 verbose stack     at emitThree (events.js:116:13)
113791 verbose stack     at emit (events.js:194:7)
113791 verbose stack     at .<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/tracker-group.js:23:18)
113791 verbose stack     at emitThree (events.js:116:13)
113791 verbose stack     at emit (events.js:194:7)
113792 verbose cwd /home/giorgi/AdMove/dev/web-advertiser-admove
113793 error Linux 4.8.0-27-generic
113794 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
113795 error node v6.9.1
113796 error npm  v3.10.8
113797 error Maximum call stack size exceeded
113798 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
113798 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
113799 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Removed `node_modules` several times and tried to reinstall. Can't understand what's the reason that causes this and how to fix it.

Comment: First of all, I'd check the github issues link for similar problems, and add it if it's not a known problem. Also, why are you trying to install v4.2.6? The current latest build is v7.1.0, and the recommended stable build is v6.9.1. Clear everything out, try 6.9.1, and update the question.

Comment: Updated to v6.9.1 still got same error and updated question also. Thanks anyway [TheEnvironmentalist](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2480092/theenvironmentalist)

Comment: Some advice around here https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10776

Comment: im my case, this was caused due to a recursive declaraion in package.json ;)

Comment: in my case, it was caused because I had lost internet connection

Comment: This is why I hate Node

Answer (score 180):

[metzelder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49750421/2754718) helped me fix the issue. however if you run the command `npm cache clean`, it will give you a message

> As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid

So, as of npm5 you can do by adding a `--force` flag to the command.

So the command is:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: On a *Node v10.15.1* and *npm 6.4.1* environment this worked like a charm! Thanks a lot.

Comment: As for me I had move the current working directory to another folder – seems like it mixed up npm. Deleting node_modules and reinstalling did the trick

Comment: @MetaGuru please explain what are the consequences of running this command...

Comment: @cdalxndr it's a joke since that's what the command says when you use the `--force` flag. ie: `npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.`

Comment: @CTS_AE I don't think the npm team added that message as a joke. There must be a consequence and someone should explain it.

Comment: @cdalxndr I was saying that it is left as a comment as a joke/satire, as a direct quote from `npm` he wasn't really adding anything helpful, but more of a meme at this point. You can read more about the actual command here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/cache.html it explicitly explains what force does; that all cache items are now fully verified for their integrity, if something is corrupt it will self heal, thus the cache should always be in a proper state and never cleared unless you're trying to reclaim disk space, thus you will need to append `--force`. Note: May vary per version.

Comment: TLDR; it will actually delete the cache like it's supposed to. Later dependency installs might go slower until re-cached.

Comment: Seems I had to do an update to npm with `npm i -g npm` then run this `npm cache clean --force` now I can finally run `npm i` 

Comment: npm suggests running `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to run with a temporary empty cache rather than deleting the real one. I would try this to see if it solves the problem before running `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: I did that with the same bad result, what did the trick for me was to update npm to the latest stable version.

Answer (score 148):

`npm rebuild`
it has solved my problem

Comment: Can anyone explain this answer further?  Why does this solve the problem?

Comment: deleted package-lock.json and npm rebuild did the trick for me

Comment: in my case, certain files in my .npm folder were installed as root.
npm cache verify tells you what is wrong.

Comment: This did the trick. npm cache clean did not work on this occasion.

Comment: from the official docs: 

> This command runs the npm build command on the matched folders. This is useful when you install a new version of node, and must recompile all your C++ addons with the new binary.

Comment: This did work for me. Thanks. Note -  However, you need to be very sure about the cache force clean.

Answer (score 96):

Try removing `package-lock.json` and the `node_modules`  folder:

```
rm package-lock.json
rm -r node_modules
```

Comment: You're killing the purpose of package-lock.json if you delete it. It guarantees that your dependencies will be deterministic.

Comment: True, but if you can't install your app on say a different platform, then you have no choice but to do this.

Comment: `npm install` should restore the `package-lock.json` file anyway

Comment: FWIW, these commands should be run inside your `functions` folder. I made the mistake of running it in the root folder

Comment: @kip2 It will produce a new `package-lock.json`, but not necessarily the same one as new versions of dependencies may be available since it was last created. It's possible that one of these new versions could break things.

Comment: @kip2 where can we read about `functions` folder, never heard of it :)

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov here's the link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#deploy_functions. In particular, note: _By default, the Firebase CLI looks in the functions/ folder for the source code. You can specify another folder by adding the following lines in firebase.json_:

"functions": {
  "source": "another-folder"
}

Answer (score 29):

I had the same issue with `npm install`.
After a lot of search, I found out that removing your `.npmrc` file or its content (found at `%USERPROFILE%/.npmrc`), will solve this issue. This worked for me.

Comment: For me this file was in: %ProgramFiles%\nodejs\node_modules\npm

Answer (score 28):

```
npm uninstall

npm cache clean --force
```

I tried these two methods but they didn't work. After, I deleted the `node_modules` directory and ran `npm install` again, it still didn't work. Lastly, I deleted `package-lock.json` and created a new `package-lock.json` file using

```
npm install
```

Comment: Deleting the package-lock.json file fixed it for me, Thanks!

Comment: I sure hope you know what you are doing.

Comment: You don't have to do. @Ibrahimshamma

Comment: This one helped me too, Thanks

Answer (score 21):

I have overcome this issue by doing following:

- Delete all the content of the npm dependencies. You can find the default install location according to this thread:
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5926706/1850297
- Before you run `npm install` command, I suggest to run `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: Message from `npm cache clean`: "As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid."

Answer (score 17):

In my case, update to the newest version:

`npm install -g npm`

Answer (score 17):

`npm rebuild` will work for sure

Comment: What does this do and how does it solve the problem?

Comment: "for sure" might be a little strong

Comment: @Menasheh npm install will install all packages and its dependencies from package json file and build it. if any dependent build failed then npm install won't stop, instead it get succeeded. but in the case of npm rebuild, it uses when you upgrade the node version and this command will rebuild the c++ addon from the beginning I mean new binary so it fixes the issue. even after this if the issue did not fix then delete package-lock file and try

Comment: @Menasheh note npm rebuild fail when any dependent addon build failure also

Answer (score 14):

I deleted

> node_modules

and then reinstalled by

> npm install

It worked for me

Comment: funny enough i had to restart ,my computer in addition to your steps for it to work, since i am working with wsl

Comment: This worked for me, but none of the other solutions did

Comment: @Avshalom THIS! For all people who run into this issue using WSL2!

Answer (score 12):

I have also faced the same problem and this is how i resolved it.

1. First of all **you need to make sure that your node and npm versions are up to date**. if not please upgrade your node and npm packages to latest versions.

   ```
   nvm install 12.18.3 // update node version through node version manager

   npm install npm // update your npm version to latest
   ```
2. Delete your `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file.
3. Force clean the entire NPM cache by using following comand.

   ```
   npm cache clean --force
   ```
4. Re-Install all the dependencies.

   ```
   npm install
   ```
5. If above step didn't resolve your problem, try to re-install your dependencies after executing following command.

   ```
   npm rebuild
   ```

Comment: I am unable to delete node_modules. I've had this occur twice. First time I had to `npm eject`, but I still had a few folders I could never remove `common-tags`, `react-dev-utils`, and `stream-browserify`.

Comment: `npm install npm` will install npm locally, which might not be what you intended. You'll want `npm install -g npm` to install it globally, overwriting the nvm installed version.

Answer (score 6):

This issue can also happen if you're trying to install a package that doesn't exist or if you're trying to install a version that doesn't exist.

Comment: how do I know which one it is, if I install numbers of them?

Comment: You need to check one by one. I use the extension version in vscode to see the latest version of each package

Answer (score 5):

> npm cache clean returns below message
>
> As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead. On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer, you can use `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.

If you run `npm cache verify`, as specified above, then it actually runs cache verification and garbage collection which fixes the problem.

> Cache verified and compressed (~\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_cacache):
> Content verified: 6183 (447214684 bytes) Content garbage-collected: 16
> (653745 bytes) Index entries: 9633

Comment: This was enough for me. npm cache verify fixed the issue in a way that removing node_modules didn't. (And I wasn't going to nuke the cache or package-lock.json). Pretty sure this is an issue with npm, though. Can't see why npm cache verify would change anything if it truly did self-heal.

Answer (score 5):

## TLDR

For those of you using *NVM*, make sure you're using the right version of *Node* & *NPM*!

## Background

I started getting this error after I started using *NVM* for a different project. When I went to run `npm install` on a project for my work, I got this error stating that the maximum call stack size had been exceeded.

This turned out to be caused by me using *Node 12* and its accompanying *NPM* version while I should've been using *Node 16*.

## Solution

Switch to a more recent version of *Node* & *NPM*;
`nvm use <version>` (for example, `nvm use 16`)

Answer (score 4):

In case none of these answer work for you, it may be because the terminal you're using isn't the right one/ your `node_modules` is used by another part of your computer.

In my case I kept juggling between this error (maximum call stack size exceeded) and the access error event when I did a `sudo npm i`.

The fix was to close my IDE (which was WebStorm), run `npm i` in a basic terminal, and that was it.

Comment: Closing the editor fixed it for me. (Netbeans for me)

Answer (score 4):

Happened in docker (node:15-buster) for me.

Remember to use `WORKDIR /<folder>` so that it doesn't conflict with original npm libraries installed.

The folder can be anything but system folders, so that includes using `/`.

Comment: I had the "call stack size exceeded" issue in docker until I moved the WORKDIR line to near the top of the Dockerfile.  Apparently the location of that line matters.

Comment: I had `WORKDIR /` at the top but it seems doing an `npm i` or `npm ci` from `/` blows things up.

Comment: @PaulRobello yep, the folder has to be separate from the original, lemme edit the answer to be clearer.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had a custom `.npmrc` file that included an auth token for authenticating with a private npm registry.

The token had expired, which helpfully returned `code E401: Incorrect or missing password` locally, but `ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded` from the CI build.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a **Windows user**, so if you are, try to check [Rene Knop comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53381497/3078787).

For **Unix/OSX** users, I've removed the root **.npmrc** file `~/.npmrc`.
Before you're going to try it, **please**,
check if there is nothing necessary over there
you can use this command to bring all content into your terminal: `cat ~/.npmrc` .

If you have got something like:

```sh
cat: /Users/$USER/.npmrc: No such file or directory
```

to save a copy:

```sh
cp ~/.npmrc ~/.npmrc_copy
```

Now, try to remove it (Works for bash users: Unix / Ubuntu / OSX ...):

```sh
rm -f ~/.npmrc
```

This worked for me.
Hope this will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same problem. I had tried the previous solutions, but the solution for me was much simpler. I only had to remove the space in the directory and then run `npm i` again

Thanks to: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/809#issuecomment-155019383 for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

In general, once a module has been installed, it's much more convenient to use `npm ci` instead of `npm install`. Please check out [this SO answer for the advantages of the former with respect to the later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499617/what-is-the-difference-between-npm-install-and-npm-ci) in a production environment.
So please just run

```
npm ci
```

All dependencies will be updated, and the problem will disappear. Or it will error in the case there's some grave de-synchronization between one and the other.

Comment: cipm can only install packages with an existing package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVersion >= 1

Comment: @SaadBilal that's what I meant with "once a module has been installed"

Comment: roger boss, you are right

Answer (score 2):

You uninstall npm package and force clean the cache and close terminal and reinstall whichever package be.

```
$sudo npm uninstall <package - name>
$sudo npm cache clean --force
```

Then restart terminal and check

Still not working upgrade both npm and node to the latest version

Answer (score 2):

Today we encountered this error when running an `npm prune` even *after* running an `npm cache clean --force`.

Versions:

```
node 13.8.0 
npm 6.13.6
```

Deleting the `package-lock.json` worked for this case as well.  Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

Most of the times, this issue occurs if you are using the system provided by the organization you work for and it's vpn restricts the use of this command.
In this case, you may try to disconnect from organization vpn and then execute this command.

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything to fix this issue on my Mac. I think the issue started when I had already downloaded npm from Node.js and then reinstalled it with Homebrew while following along with a Team Treehouse video.

## Here's what I tried:

From https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/removing-npm

```
sudo npm uninstall npm -g
sudo make uninstall
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/npm*
```

From [How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/{npm*,node*,man1/node*}
```

## Here's what worked:

In the end, the only thing that worked for me was to clone down the npm-reinstall repo from GitHub that completely removed everything related to npm on my Mac.

https://github.com/brock/node-reinstall

I then had to reinstall node and npm from Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything to fix this issue on my windows 7 machine like

Reinstalling and rebuilding npm

At last, I fixed this small configuration setting issue by wasting my entire day.

## How I resolved this issue

Removing my project specific configurations in global .npmrc 
at location like drive:/Windows/Users/../.npmrc

Answer (score 1):

I solved it 100% I had this problem with gulp version: 3.5.6.

You should clean the package-lock.js and then run `npm install` and It worked form

Answer (score 1):

Our company dev environment uses `Artifactory` as the default registry for our NPM dependencies, and when running `npm install` it was defaulting to this, which did not work... so manually specifying the main npm registry via `npm install --registry https://registry.npmjs.org` fixed this issue for me...

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error, I was trying to install jest into to one of the packages in a monorepo project.

If you are using Yarn + Learna to package a monorepo project, you will have to navigate to the package.json inside the target package and then run `npm install` or `npm install <package name>`.

Answer (score 1):

## Try this first!

**Run `npm install` again**

Crazily simple, but I don't know who else tried this so thought I should put it up here, despite all the existing answers. I suggest people try this *first* though, given it's the simplest solution and doesn't come with the risks others have noted when, say, deleting package-lock.json

### Theory:

This is totally unproven as I'm just doing this to run a code screen (i.e. a totally new repo to me) and I guessed that some of the packages had been installed the first time `npm install` was run; it just ran out of resources later on.

I guessed that if I ran `npm install` again it would skip the install of the now-installed packages and complete, or at least get further. The behaviour I guessed at was what I saw but I didn't actually debug or test if this behaviour was for the reasons I guessed!

Clearly a lot of different things have worked for different people, but I thought I should add an answer to this already well-answered question on the basis it's the most trivial to do.

And if you're lucky it's going to run for long enough for you to grab a  or ☕

Comment: As strange as it sounds, running the npm install again worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was due to an upgrade of my git executable.  I rolled back to Git-2.21.0.rc1.windows.1-64-bit and added this to my environment path and it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that finally worked for me on Mac was upgrading from node 8.12 to 10.x using NVM.

I uninstalled all other versions of Node with NVM, then installed 10.x, then ran `nvm alias default node`, which tells NVM to always default to the latest available node version on a shell.

After that, my live reloading issue went away!

Answer (score 0):

Switching to yarn solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

For those having this issue when building a Docker image with Jenkins (or any CI), make sure the `package-lock.json` is also copied to the container.

```
COPY ./src/package*.json /home/node/
RUN npm install
```

For us, the install actually went fine, the error only occurred when running `npm prune production` for the production image.

Comment: I have this problem with npm prune and NODE_ENV not set to production. Solved by removing node_modules and npm install again

Answer (score 0):

If your default npm registry is something other than the public npm repository (you can check this by going to your .npmrc file or checking your npm config via npm CLI commands), you could try unsetting the registry config so it points back to the public npm repository. Then run `npm install` again.

If you have dependencies that aren't available in the public npm repository, try temporarily removing those dependencies from package.json. This will allow you to run `npm install`. Finally, revert the dependencies and registry config you removed and run `npm install` one last time to install the rest of your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar error.  I tracked it down to the fact that npm was unable to delete files from the .bin folders for a npm link'd folder.  So I went in and rm -rf all the .bin folders from the npm link'd folder.

```
find "linked-folder" -type d -name ".bin" -print  
For all folders listed | rm -rf
```

That resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps helped me to solve this issue:

1. Stop all react strips (e.g. start build)
2. run `npm cache clean --force`
3. run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 65536 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

works for me on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm cache clean --force
```

This works for me with node 8, and npm 6+

Answer (score 0):

The error message may not be directly related to the npm procedure you are trying to run, it might be other node processes running that conflict or use up resources.

In my case I had an empty node_modules folder fresh from a recent init and still got

> npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

when running `npm install --save-dev @wordpress/scripts` for WordPress plugin development.

The issue was a live reload watcher running in my wp-content folder, with that stopped the install worked first time.

Answer (score 0):

[In my case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63831755/2771889) `Maximum call stack size exceeded` was triggered by another error earlier. The logs looked like this:

```
// ... skipping some deprecation warnings

> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.10.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-graphql-types-generator/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

sh: 1: node: Permission denied
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-09-10T14_10_28_397Z-debug.log
```

Note `sh: 1: node: Permission denied` that led me to https://forum.vuejs.org/t/cannot-install-vue-cli-permission-error-in-require-postinstall/82017/7

I had to add `--unsafe-perm` to the install command and run it as root:

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm @aws-amplify/cli
```

Comment: It works for me with I am using npm on Windows WSL subsystem. `npm install --unsafe-perm`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it turned out, I had a symbolic link inside `node_modules` pointing to it's parent, i.e.

```
[user@localhost]$ ls -la /path/to/project/node_modules
total 3272
...
lrwxrwxrwx   1 user user  50 Nov 26 18:38 node_modules -> ../node_modules
...
```

I mean, somehow I messed the bash script and it created a circular symbolic link. Removing the symbolic link solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

and then reinstall worked for me.

<sub>note: probably don't need to rip out your lock files</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I tried all suggestions in this thread but none of them working, I keep getting `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` when I run 'npm install'. I decide to run `npm start` directly, and it start successfully whit no error...

Answer (score 0):

delete your node_modules directory and package-lock.json files and reinstall your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing, check if you're in the right folder that has your node_modules.

Answer (score -1):

I came across to same problem but in my case I have been using `yarn` from beginning but from some package readme I copied the `npm install` command and got this error. Later realised that `yarn add <package-name>` solved the issue and package was installed.

It might help someone in future.