# [webpack]: npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

While doing `npm i -D webpack` I am getting the following error.

```
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/shobhuiy1/.npm/_logs/2019-02-05T10_31_29_468Z-debug.log
```

Using MacOs. node v10.15.1, npm v6.4.1

I tried doing `npm cache clean --force`, it doesn't help.

Attaching the log below.

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok 1 verbose cli [
>   '/usr/local/bin/node', 1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm', 1 verbose
>   cli   'i', 1 verbose cli   '-D', 1 verbose cli   'webpack' ] 2 info
>   using npm@6.4.1 3 info using node@v10.15.1 4 verbose npm-session
>   8116f23fee5883fe 5 silly install loadCurrentTree 6 silly install
>   readLocalPackageData 7 http fetch GET 304
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack 266ms (from cache) 8 silly pacote
>   tag manifest for webpack@latest fetched in 295ms 9 timing
>   stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 530ms 10 silly install
>   loadIdealTree 11 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree 12 timing
>   stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 0ms 13 silly install
>   loadShrinkwrap 14 timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed
>   in 1ms 15 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree 16 silly
>   resolveWithNewModule webpack@4.29.1 checking installable status 17
>   http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@webassemblyjs%2fast
>   78ms (from cache) 18 silly pacote version manifest for
>   @webassemblyjs/ast@1.7.11 fetched in 81ms 19 silly
>   resolveWithNewModule @webassemblyjs/ast@1.7.11 checking installable
>   status 20 http fetch GET 304
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/chrome-trace-event 114ms (from cache) 21
>   http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn 118ms (from cache)
>   22 silly pacote range manifest for chrome-trace-event@^1.0.0 fetched
>   in 116ms 23 silly resolveWithNewModule chrome-trace-event@1.0.0
>   checking installable status 24 silly pacote range manifest for
>   acorn@^6.0.5 fetched in 122ms 25 silly resolveWithNewModule
>   acorn@6.0.7 checking installable status 26 http fetch GET 304
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-scope 52ms (from cache) 27 silly
>   pacote range manifest for eslint-scope@^4.0.0 fetched in 53ms 28 silly
>   resolveWithNewModule eslint-scope@4.0.0 checking installable status 29
>   http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ajv-keywords 145ms (from
>   cache) 30 silly pacote range manifest for ajv-keywords@^3.1.0 fetched
>   in 148ms 31 silly resolveWithNewModule ajv-keywords@3.3.0 checking
>   installable status 32 http fetch GET 304
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/@webassemblyjs%2fhelper-module-context
>   158ms (from cache) 33 silly pacote version manifest for
>   @webassemblyjs/helper-module-context@1.7.11 fetched in 162ms 34 silly
>   resolveWithNewModule @webassemblyjs/helper-module-context@1.7.11
>   checking installable status 35 http fetch GET 304
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/@webassemblyjs%2fwasm-edit 165ms (from
>   cache) 36 silly pacote version manifest for
>   @webassemblyjs/wasm-edit@1.7.11 fetched in 172ms 37 silly
>   resolveWithNewModule @webassemblyjs/wasm-edit@1.7.11 checking
>   installable status 38 http fetch GET 304
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/json-parse-better-errors 54ms (from cache)
>   39 silly pacote range manifest for json-parse-better-errors@^1.0.2
>   fetched in 60ms 40 silly resolveWithNewModule
>   json-parse-better-errors@1.0.2 checking installable status 41 http
>   fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ajv 184ms (from cache) 42
>   http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/loader-runner 70ms (from
>   cache) 43 http fetch GET 304
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/enhanced-resolve 190ms (from cache) 44
>   silly pacote range manifest for ajv@^6.1.0 fetched in 195ms 45 silly
>   resolveWithNewModule ajv@6.8.1 checking installable status 46 silly
>   pacote range manifest for loader-runner@^2.3.0 fetched in 78ms 47
>   silly resolveWithNewModule loader-runner@2.4.0 checking installable
>   status 48 silly pacote range manifest for enhanced-resolve@^4.1.0
>   fetched in 198ms 49 silly resolveWithNewModule enhanced-resolve@4.1.0
>   checking installable status 50 http fetch GET 304
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn-dynamic-import 212ms (from cache) 51
>   http fetch GET 304
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/@webassemblyjs%2fwasm-parser 216ms (from
>   cache) 52 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/loader-utils
>   83ms (from cache) 53 silly pacote range manifest for
>   acorn-dynamic-import@^4.0.0 fetched in 216ms 54 silly
>   resolveWithNewModule acorn-dynamic-import@4.0.0 checking installable
>   status 55 silly pacote version manifest for
>   @webassemblyjs/wasm-parser@1.7.11 fetched in 220ms 56 silly
>   resolveWithNewModule @webassemblyjs/wasm-parser@1.7.11 checking
>   installable status 57 silly pacote range manifest for
>   loader-utils@^1.1.0 fetched in 87ms 58 silly resolveWithNewModule
>   loader-utils@1.2.3 checking installable status 59 http fetch GET 304
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/memory-fs 77ms (from cache) 60 http fetch
>   GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/micromatch 71ms (from cache) 61
>   silly pacote range manifest for memory-fs@~0.4.1 fetched in 80ms 62
>   silly resolveWithNewModule memory-fs@0.4.1 checking installable status
>   63 silly pacote range manifest for micromatch@^3.1.8 fetched in 78ms
>   64 silly resolveWithNewModule micromatch@3.1.10 checking installable
>   status 65 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp 70ms
>   (from cache) 66 http fetch GET 304
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/neo-async 62ms (from cache) 67 silly pacote
>   range manifest for mkdirp@~0.5.0 fetched in 75ms 68 silly
>   resolveWithNewModule mkdirp@0.5.1 checking installable status 69 silly
>   pacote range manifest for neo-async@^2.5.0 fetched in 65ms 70 silly
>   resolveWithNewModule neo-async@2.6.0 checking installable status 71
>   http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-libs-browser 49ms
>   (from cache) 72 silly pacote range manifest for
>   node-libs-browser@^2.0.0 fetched in 50ms 73 silly resolveWithNewModule
>   node-libs-browser@2.2.0 checking installable status 74 http fetch GET
>   304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tapable 56ms (from cache) 75 http fetch
>   GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/terser-webpack-plugin 44ms (from
>   cache) 76 silly pacote range manifest for tapable@^1.1.0 fetched in
>   59ms 77 silly resolveWithNewModule tapable@1.1.1 checking installable
>   status 78 silly pacote range manifest for terser-webpack-plugin@^1.1.0
>   fetched in 46ms 79 silly resolveWithNewModule
>   terser-webpack-plugin@1.2.2 checking installable status 80 http fetch
>   GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/schema-utils 64ms (from cache) 81
>   silly pacote range manifest for schema-utils@^0.4.4 fetched in 65ms 82
>   silly resolveWithNewModule schema-utils@0.4.7 checking installable
>   status 83 http fetch GET 304
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack-sources 58ms (from cache) 84 silly
>   pacote range manifest for webpack-sources@^1.3.0 fetched in 59ms 85
>   silly resolveWithNewModule webpack-sources@1.3.0 checking installable
>   status 86 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/watchpack 60ms
>   (from cache) 87 silly pacote range manifest for watchpack@^1.5.0
>   fetched in 61ms 88 silly resolveWithNewModule watchpack@1.6.0 checking
>   installable status 89 http fetch GET 304
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/@webassemblyjs%2fwast-parser 50ms (from
>   cache) 90 silly pacote version manifest for
>   @webassemblyjs/wast-parser@1.7.11 fetched in 53ms 91 silly
>   resolveWithNewModule @webassemblyjs/wast-parser@1.7.11 checking
>   installable status 92 http fetch GET 304
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/@webassemblyjs%2fhelper-wasm-bytecode 57ms
>   (from cache) 93 silly pacote version manifest for
>   @webassemblyjs/helper-wasm-bytecode@1.7.11 fetched in 59ms 94 silly
>   resolveWithNewModule @webassemblyjs/helper-wasm-bytecode@1.7.11
>   checking installable status 95 http fetch GET 304
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/@webassemblyjs%2fhelper-api-error 58ms
>   (from cache) 96 http fetch GET 304
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/@webassemblyjs%2fhelper-fsm 58ms (from
>   cache) 97 http fetch GET 304
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/@webassemblyjs%2fhelper-code-frame 60ms
>   (from cache) 98 silly pacote version manifest for
>   @webassemblyjs/helper-api-error@1.7.11 fetched in 62ms 99 silly
>   resolveWithNewModule @webassemblyjs/helper-api-error@1.7.11 checking
>   installable status 100 silly pacote version manifest for
>   @webassemblyjs/helper-fsm@1.7.11 fetched in 62ms 101 silly
>   resolveWithNewModule @webassemblyjs/helper-fsm@1.7.11 checking
>   installable status 102 silly pacote version manifest for
>   @webassemblyjs/helper-code-frame@1.7.11 fetched in 63ms 103 silly
>   resolveWithNewModule @webassemblyjs/helper-code-frame@1.7.11 checking
>   installable status 104 http fetch GET 304
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/@webassemblyjs%2ffloating-point-hex-parser
>   65ms (from cache) 105 silly pacote version manifest for
>   @webassemblyjs/floating-point-hex-parser@1.7.11 fetched in 66ms 106
>   silly resolveWithNewModule
>   @webassemblyjs/floating-point-hex-parser@1.7.11 checking installable
>   status 107 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/@xtuc%2flong
>   474ms 108 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @xtuc/long@4.2.1 404
>   Not Found: @xtuc/long@4.2.1 109 verbose stack RangeError: Maximum call
>   stack size exceeded 109 verbose stack     at RegExp.test ()
>   109 verbose stack     at isDepOptional
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:405:45) 109
>   verbose stack     at failedDependency
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:414:9) 109
>   verbose stack     at failedDependency
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:430:9) 109
>   verbose stack     at failedDependency
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:430:9) 109
>   verbose stack     at failedDependency
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:430:9) 109
>   verbose stack     at failedDependency
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:430:9) 109
>   verbose stack     at failedDependency
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:430:9) 109
>   verbose stack     at failedDependency
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:430:9) 109
>   verbose stack     at failedDependency
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:430:9) 109
>   verbose stack     at failedDependency
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:430:9) 109
>   verbose stack     at failedDependency
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:430:9) 109
>   verbose stack     at failedDependency
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:430:9) 109
>   verbose stack     at failedDependency
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:430:9) 109
>   verbose stack     at failedDependency
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:430:9) 109
>   verbose stack     at failedDependency
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:430:9) 110
>   verbose cwd
>   /Users/shobhuiy1/Documents/shouvik-personal/softwares-dev/spliwise-react-redux
>   111 verbose Darwin 17.7.0 112 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node"
>   "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "-D" "webpack" 113 verbose node v10.15.1 114
>   verbose npm  v6.4.1 115 error Maximum call stack size exceeded 116
>   verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: What does your `2019-02-05T10_31_29_468Z-debug.log` say?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum call stack size exceeded on npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566348/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-on-npm-install)

Comment: solutions given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566348/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-on-npm-install didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the npm configurations were somehow modified / corrupted.

I uninstalled node and npm from my machine and reinstalled node, worked for me.

Steps to uninstall node with brew.

```
brew uninstall node

brew cleanup
```

Steps to uninstall node manually, without brew.

> delete node and npm from /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 0):

First, remove node_modules folder.

Then,

**npm cache clean --f**

Finally, reinstall dependencies

**npm i**