# npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded when npm install (angular)

Tags: angular, npm

i got this when running npm install

```
npm WARN deprecated ts-simple-ast@12.4.0: NOTICE: ts-simple-ast has been renamed to ts-morph and version reset to 1.0.0. Switch at your leisure...
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN deprecated nodemailer@2.7.2: All versions below 4.0.1 of Nodemailer are deprecated. See https://nodemailer.com/status/
npm WARN deprecated nomnom@1.5.2: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
npm WARN deprecated mailcomposer@4.0.1: This project is unmaintained
npm WARN deprecated socks@1.1.9: If using 2.x branch, please upgrade to at least 2.1.6 to avoid a serious bug with socket data flow and an
import issue introduced in 2.1.0
npm WARN deprecated uws@9.14.0: New code is available at github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets.js
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated buildmail@4.0.1: This project is unmaintained
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\1-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-22T21_56_49_385Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What npm install command are you running and where (which folder) are you running it in? What version of npm do you have?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566348/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-on-npm-install

Comment: @Salma Ahmed, please add more details. You can find guidelines on how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please share package.json file and some details

Answer (score 4):

Go to your project directory and remove **node_modules** folder,

> rm -rf node_modules

Then clean your cache,

> npm cache clean --f

Finally reinstall dependencies,

> npm i

Comment: This is the best answer. 9 times out of 10, it was the `node_modules` folder causing the issue (and not even a cache clear helps).

Comment: Yes remove the folder node_modules works, in my case the folder location is C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

Answer (score 4):

I used Docker to build a react project and got a similar error (although this error was not repeated locally). This error is returned due to nesting limitations of the recursive call.

As a workaround, the following command helped me, which increase the maximum number of recursive calls:

> node --stack-size=2000 /local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js install

I found this solution on the [Russian-language forum](http://pyha.ru/forum/topic/9396.1)

Comment: This is a bit sorter w/o writing out the whole directory `node --stack-size=2000 $(which npm) install`

Comment: @CTS_AE is a neater command. But don't forget to use backticks, or you'll get EOF error
*node --stack-size=2000 \`$(which npm) install\` *

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when I run the `create-react-app` command. Although the command is different the create react app scaffolding does run `npm i` command as well when triggered for installing various dependencies.

- Delete the global `.npmrc` file located in `C:/<name of the root folder>/nvm/v12.18.3/node_modules/npm`
- Run
  `npm cache clean --force`
  outside the project folder
- Then again run the `npm i` inside the project folder that should fix the issue.

Code Editor: Visual Studio Code running in administrator mode.

Host operating system: Microsoft Windows 10.

Using NVM to run Node.js in Windows 10.