# react nodegui call stack exceeded error when using GridView/ BoxView components

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am getting `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` on `npm start`
when using the above components.
the dev server with `npm run dev` runs without errors.

- I have tried the `npm cache clean -f` solution suggested most of the time for such errors [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54838301/7562284)

```
> npm start

> mavlink-viewer@1.0.0 start /home/rmarzooqur/playgs/topcoder/active/mavlink-viewer
> qode ./dist/index.js

The above error occurred in the <gridview> component:
    in gridview (created by App)
    in mainwindow (created by App)
    in App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
/home/rmarzooqur/playgs/topcoder/active/mavlink-viewer/dist/index.js:37901
      throw error;
      ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at RNGridView.get layout [as layout] (/home/rmarzooqur/playgs/topcoder/active/mavlink-viewer/dist/index.js:18064:15)
    at RNGridView.get layout [as layout] (/home/rmarzooqur/playgs/topcoder/active/mavlink-viewer/dist/index.js:18065:21)
    at RNGridView.get layout [as layout] (/home/rmarzooqur/playgs/topcoder/active/mavlink-viewer/dist/index.js:18065:21)
    at RNGridView.get layout [as layout] (/home/rmarzooqur/playgs/topcoder/active/mavlink-viewer/dist/index.js:18065:21)
    at RNGridView.get layout [as layout] (/home/rmarzooqur/playgs/topcoder/active/mavlink-viewer/dist/index.js:18065:21)
    at RNGridView.get layout [as layout] (/home/rmarzooqur/playgs/topcoder/active/mavlink-viewer/dist/index.js:18065:21)
    at RNGridView.get layout [as layout] (/home/rmarzooqur/playgs/topcoder/active/mavlink-viewer/dist/index.js:18065:21)
    at RNGridView.get layout [as layout] (/home/rmarzooqur/playgs/topcoder/active/mavlink-viewer/dist/index.js:18065:21)
    at RNGridView.get layout [as layout] (/home/rmarzooqur/playgs/topcoder/active/mavlink-viewer/dist/index.js:18065:21)
    at RNGridView.get layout [as layout] (/home/rmarzooqur/playgs/topcoder/active/mavlink-viewer/dist/index.js:18065:21)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mavlink-viewer@1.0.0 start: `qode ./dist/index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mavlink-viewer@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rmarzooqur/.npm/_logs/2021-08-04T07_30_55_333Z-debug.log
```