# npm err! maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am using NPM and the project was going all fine. After a while, I deleted the `node_modules` folder and started getting the error.
System : Macbook Pro

```
2814 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
2815 verbose node v11.9.0
2816 verbose npm  v6.5.0
2817 error Maximum call stack size exceeded
2818 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Fixes tried: 
Removed the package-lock.json and tried with `npm i` -> Still it gives the same error.
Tried with `npm rebuild` -> no luck
Tried with `npm cache-clean --force` -> no luck

While doing the investigation - if I remove `"@frctl/fractal": "^1.1.7"` from `devDependencies` - npm install works fine. Since, it was working fine until now. So, don't know the real cause of it.
Below is the `devDependencies` list:

```
"devDependencies": {
"@frctl/fractal": "^1.1.7",
"@frctl/mandelbrot": "^1.2.0",
"node-sass": "^4.11.0",
"angular": "^1.3.15",
"typescript": "^3.2.2",
"autoprefixer": "^6.7.7",
"browser-sync": "^2.18.8",
"del": "^2.2.2",
"glob": "^7.1.1",
"gulp": "^4.0.0",
"gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
"gulp-changed": "^2.0.0",
"gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
"gulp-environments": "^0.1.2",
"gulp-flatten": "^0.3.1",
"gulp-htmlmin": "^3.0.0",
"gulp-iconfont": "^10.0.2",
"gulp-iconfont-css": "^2.3.0",
"gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
"gulp-imagemin": "^3.2.0",
"gulp-notify": "^3.0.0",
"gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
"gulp-postcss": "^6.4.0",
"gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
"gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
"gulp-sass-glob": "^1.0.8",
"gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.4.1",
"gulp-surge": "^0.1.0",
"gulp-svg-sprite": "^1.3.6",
"gulp-svgmin": "^1.2.3",
"gulp-uglify": "^2.1.2",
"merge-stream": "^1.0.1",
"require-dir": "^0.3.1",
"@types/angular": "^1.6.53",
"@types/angular-mocks": "^1.7.0",
"@types/jasmine": "^3.3.7",
"@types/karma": "^1.7.1",
"@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
"angular-mocks": "1.3.15",
"jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
"jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
"karma": "^1.7.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
"karma-cli": "1.0.1",
"karma-coverage": "^1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
"karma-jquery": "^0.2.3",
"karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
"karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
"karma-typescript": "^3.0.13",
"ts-mockito": "^2.3.1",
"ts-node": "^8.0.1",
"@types/angular-translate": "^2.16.0",
"grunt": "^0.4.5",
"grunt-cli": "^0.1.13",
"grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.1",
"@types/lodash": "^4.14.121"
}
```

Any suggestions for resolving this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this suggestion [npm rebuild -g](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53184733/4855817) work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if anyone has encountered this kind of issue or not. I fixed the issue by generating the package-lock.json and it fixes the build issue. Thanks for the support!

Comment: I can't understand generating the `package-lock.json`.  Basically, as I know, package-lock.json is automatically generated. Is there a way to manually configure `package-lock.json`?

Comment: just delete package-lock.json and run npm install. then it gets generated.

Answer (score 2):

I too had this same issues

```
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/veluvijay/.npm/_logs/2019-12-09T05_54_58_567Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
See "/tmp/ng-K4aXCl/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

After updating the nodejs from **version 10** to **version 12.03.1**, it  work's fine on my machine.

Comment: I have same problem so I tried to upgrade node version to latest stable version. `14.x.x`.
But I still got an issue. It doesn't look like the main reason is related to node version.

Comment: @AdelinIonut were you able to find any solution to fix this error?

Comment: Not really, I haven't solved that issue yet.