# npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded on Linux

Tags: npm-install

I use npm to install new component built by ReactJs. I can successfully install it on local windows machine. However, when I tried to use AWS codeBuild to build my client project, I encountered the following error in virtual machine:

npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

My npm version is 6.4.1.

When the build starts, the build process actually download npm and start to install packages based on package.json. So it is like to install packages on brand new machine.

I've tried to search online to see if there is anything similar and I couldn't find any solution.

Just plain 'npm install'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum call stack size exceeded on npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566348/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-on-npm-install)

Comment: Can you share buildspec.yml

Comment: - apt-get install -y yarn
- apt install nodejs npm
- nodejs --version
- apt-get install -y p7zip-full
npm install

Comment: "npm install" works fine locally on my machine. It just give me that error message on Linux based virtual machine.