# npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded while creating a react project using create-react-app

Tags: reactjs

On creating a react application using create-react-app,I am getting error :

```
C:\Users\NidaZehra\Desktop\React>create-react-app demo1

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\NidaZehra\Desktop\React\demo1.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Please help me out !!

Comment: Try to execute `npm cache clean --force` and re-run CRA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum call stack size exceeded on npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566348/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-on-npm-install)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to to increase the call stack size by append --max_old_space_size=4096 to the command.

```
create-react-app demo1 --max_old_space_size=4096
```

Still it's not a very common issue, what operationg system and amount of RAM do you have?