# Got 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' console error while installing ember-cli-mirage

Tags: node.js, npm, ember-cli

I'm trying to install ember-cli-mirage via ember-clim but got error in console:

```
Command failed: npm install --save-dev --loglevel error ember-cli-mirage
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.4.1: core-js@<2.6.8 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/vitaliy/.npm/_logs/2019-08-13T10_31_36_432Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Node.js version - v8.16.0
npm version - 6.4.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum call stack size exceeded on npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566348/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-on-npm-install)