# Configure SharePoint Framework

Tags: node.js, npm, sharepoint-online, spfx

I'm trying configure SharePoint FrameWork following [this exercise](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/learn/modules/sharepoint-spfx-get-started/5-exercise-setup-development-environment).

I have installed nodejs (version v12.18.0) and npm (version 6.14.4).

When I run the following command:

```
npm install --global yo
```

I receive this response:

> ```
> C:\Users\Familia Ramos>npm install --global yo
> npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.5: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fsevents):
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
> ```

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,

I have made it work, activating the programmer mode in the windows settings

Regards

Answer (score 0):

> "The current supported LTS version of NodeJS for the SharePoint Framework is **Node.js v8.x** and **Node.js v10.x**. Notice that 9.x, 11.x or 12.x versions are currently not supported with SharePoint Framework development. Above links are pointing to 10.20.1 version."

Just follow [official guide here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment).

Answer (score 0):

With version 10, it still gives me the same results

```
C:\Windows\system32>node -v
v10.21.0

C:\Windows\system32>npm -v
6.14.4

C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g yo gulp
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.5: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Comment: Try the solution in the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566348/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-on-npm-install