# Unable to create new react native Project (react-native init Myproject)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules

I'm unable create a new Project in React native. Used Command is **react-native init Myproject**.
Please refer the below image.

[image]

Comment: [Maximum call stack size exceeded on npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566348/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-on-npm-install)

Comment: @paul-shuvo . If I run the command **npm cache clean --force**, may it affect my existing projects..??

Comment: do you have this error every time you use `npm install` or while using `react-native init`?

Comment: This error shows only when i create new project (`react-native init`).. In existing project when i run `npm install` it works fine..

Comment: remove the global binary `react-native` and try with `npx react-native init Myproject`

Comment: @paul-shuvo. Thanks paul-shuvo... it works with this command..`npm cache clean --force`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have memory issues with npm, try to clean cache :

```
`npm cache clean`
```

or
`npm cache clean --force`

and if it's a new project why not using yarn ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

1. Remove the global binary **react-native**
2. Run `npx react-native init Myproject`