# Error while installing react app. an error occured while installing react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was creating a new react app. while i  type "npx create-react-app my-app", it shows an error of

```
npx: installed 67 in 43.033s

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\Projects\REAT sample\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Toshiba\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-26T04_28_43_111Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\Projects\REAT sample
Done.
```

Comment: Does this question help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566348/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-on-npm-install

Comment: Can you help to provide what's inside `2021-02-26T04_28_43_111Z-debug.log` too?
Just tested with `npm 12.18.3` and `npx 6.14.9`, and it still works.