# ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded running on Azure App Service

Tags: node.js, npm, azure-web-app-service, npm-workspaces

I have a Node.js and Vue web app with code on Bitbucket that I'd like to run on Azure App Service. The code uses npm workspaces. Many things work:

- Pushing to `main` triggers a new Oryx build on Azure.
- The build completes successfully.
- The app service restarts, finds the tar.gz bundled node_modules, and attempts to install.

Then npm throws an error: "Maximum call stack size exceeded":

```
2022-05-26T22:30:56.622181753Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2022-05-26T22:30:56.622185053Z NodeJS quickstart: https://aka.ms/node-qs
2022-05-26T22:30:56.622188353Z NodeJS Version : v16.13.1
2022-05-26T22:30:56.622191753Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2022-05-26T22:30:56.622195353Z 
2022-05-26T22:30:57.671975654Z Starting periodic command scheduler: cron.
2022-05-26T22:30:57.819864556Z Found build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'. Deserializing it...
2022-05-26T22:30:57.823023597Z Build Operation ID: |mTOdVwRHTgA=.4c8dcbcb_
2022-05-26T22:30:57.840196418Z Environment Variables for Application Insight's IPA Codeless Configuration exists..
2022-05-26T22:30:58.384540918Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470679226Z Running #!/bin/sh
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470711626Z 
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470717626Z # Enter the source directory to make sure the script runs where the user expects
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470722627Z cd "/home/site/wwwroot"
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470734227Z 
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470738827Z export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470743427Z if [ -z "$PORT" ]; then
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470748127Z      export PORT=8080
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470752927Z fi
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470757227Z 
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470761427Z echo Found tar.gz based node_modules.
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470766327Z extractionCommand="tar -xzf node_modules.tar.gz -C /node_modules"
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470770927Z echo "Removing existing modules directory from root..."
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470775527Z rm -fr /node_modules
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470779827Z mkdir -p /node_modules
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470784227Z echo Extracting modules...
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470788627Z $extractionCommand
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470792927Z export NODE_PATH="/node_modules":$NODE_PATH
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470797528Z export PATH=/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470802228Z if [ -d node_modules ]; then
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470806628Z     mv -f node_modules _del_node_modules || true
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470823228Z fi
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470827528Z 
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470831428Z if [ -d /node_modules ]; then
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470835428Z     ln -sfn /node_modules ./node_modules 
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470839528Z fi
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470843428Z 
2022-05-26T22:30:58.470847328Z echo "Done."
2022-05-26T22:30:58.478721429Z PATH="$PATH:/home/site/wwwroot" npm i && npm start
2022-05-26T22:30:58.490088376Z Found tar.gz based node_modules.
2022-05-26T22:30:58.490684883Z Removing existing modules directory from root...
2022-05-26T22:30:58.529059677Z Extracting modules...
2022-05-26T22:31:10.105548413Z Done.
2022-05-26T22:31:11.551727987Z npm info it worked if it ends with ok
2022-05-26T22:31:11.560135195Z npm info using npm@6.14.15
2022-05-26T22:31:11.561597313Z npm info using node@v16.13.1
2022-05-26T22:31:15.244181354Z npm info lifecycle my-app@0.0.1~preinstall: my-app@0.0.1
2022-05-26T22:31:19.567653504Z npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
2022-05-26T22:31:19.593524734Z npm timing npm Completed in 8150ms
2022-05-26T22:31:19.597115780Z 
2022-05-26T22:31:19.598435196Z npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2022-05-26T22:31:19.599027604Z npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-05-26T22_31_19_569Z-debug.log
```

I'm not sure of the cause of the error, but I did notice that the app is run with npm version 6.14.15, which as far as I'm aware doesn't support npm workspaces. Is it possible to upgrade npm? I tried using `WEBSITE_NPM_DEFAULT_VERSION` but that didn't appear to have any effect. I noticed that the Oryx build uses npm version 8.5.0.

Comment: check this--https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566348/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-on-npm-install?rq=1

Comment: @RajkumarMamidiChettu-MT Thanks for the link. I tried a few of those, but most of them seem intended for local development machines.