# AWS-CDK returning maximum call stack size exceed when installing with npm

Tags: npm-install, aws-cdk

I'm getting an error when I run `npm install -g aws-cdk` it says `Maximum call stack size exceeded` if I don't do the global install then I don't get that error but my windows machine doesn't pick up that I have AWS-CDK installed then. The documentation also says to install globally.

Has anyone encountered this?

An important note I am using a company PC that sits behind a VPN. I can't however disconnect this from the VPN.

I'm running version 16.18.0 node and version 8.19.2 of npm

The log file where the error is:

````
37 verbose stack     at resolve (node:path:158:10)
37 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\realpath.js:21:10)
37 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\realpath.js:41:10)
37 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\realpath.js:41:10)
37 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\realpath.js:41:10)
37 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\realpath.js:41:10)
37 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\realpath.js:41:10)
37 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\realpath.js:41:10)
37 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\realpath.js:41:10)
37 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\realpath.js:41:10)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. My problem is that I work on a PC with roaming profiles where APPDATA is redirected to a server share. In my case changing the `npm prefix directory` solved the issue. Try the following:

> npm config --global get prefix

In my case the output was: `\\SRV02\Profiles\USERNAME_HERE\AppData\Roaming\npm`

I changed it using the following command

> npm config --global set prefix C:\tools\npm-prefix

then everything works. Remember to add C:\tools\npm-prefix to the PATH environment variable

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to something in your global node_modules directory and not the AWS CDK.  Try some answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566348/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-on-npm-install#51336567) first.

Comment: I tried all of those solutions and nothing got it working. Is there maybe a hacky way I can install it? Like I said the non global install works but not the global one