# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded on npm start

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, package.json

I am getting the error react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
throw err;
I am trying to run npm start, and this error occurs. It came from nowhere i do not know what happend

```
D:\Programowanie\Ujccap\client\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.isExpressionWithTypeArguments (D:\Programowanie\Ujccap\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:29486:43)
    at Object.tryGetClassImplementingOrExtendingExpressionWithTypeArguments (D:\Programowanie\Ujccap\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:19246:19)
    at getTypeOfNode (D:\Programowanie\Ujccap\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:88475:32)
    at getTypeOfVariableOrParameterOrPropertyWorker (D:\Programowanie\Ujccap\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:57771:30)
    at getTypeOfVariableOrParameterOrProperty (D:\Programowanie\Ujccap\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:57728:28)
    at getTypeOfSymbol (D:\Programowanie\Ujccap\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:58114:24)
    at getNarrowedTypeOfSymbol (D:\Programowanie\Ujccap\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:73170:20)
    at checkIdentifier (D:\Programowanie\Ujccap\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:73246:24)
    at checkExpressionWorker (D:\Programowanie\Ujccap\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:81571:28)
    at checkExpression (D:\Programowanie\Ujccap\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:81520:38)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum call stack size exceeded on npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566348/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-on-npm-install)

Comment: nope, still same issue

Comment: trying to solve it, and now this error occured

Comment: RpcIpcMessagePortClosedError: Process 12936 exited with code "1" [null]
Issues checking service aborted - probably out of memory. Check the `memoryLimit` option in the ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin configuration.