# I am not able to uninstall nodejs. After I got the error module not found "node-uuid"

Tags: node.js, angular

I tried to install angular2 quickstart https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html#!#develop-locally Then I got the error node-uuid module not found.  I tried following these links  https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/15310 but its not working :( .

```
Error: Cannot find module 'node-uuid'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\lib\auth.js:4:12)

    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

Please let me know how to get npm install work again.

Answer (score 0):

Most NPM issues can be fixed with this process :

In your project

`rm -rf /node_modules`

`npm cache clean`

Find your [global](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5926706/5645292) `node_modules`

> You can run npm list -g to see where global libraries are installed.
>
> On Unix systems they are normally placed in /usr/local/lib/node or
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules when installed globally. If you set the
>   NODE_PATH environment variable to this path, the modules can be found
>   by node.
>
> Windows XP - %USERPROFILE%\Application Data\npm\node_modules
>
> Windows 7 [ - 10]
>   - %AppData%\npm\node_modules

`rm -rf /node_modules`

Back to your project

`npm install`

Comment: PS: you can use `npm i` instead of `npm install` as an `shorthand`

Comment: ...yes. you can

Comment: Thanks pardeep and Daniel. For me as of now npm list command is also not working. So I am trying to remove the node modules  from the installed folder as suggested and then will try installing again.