# How can I install the latest version of Typescript without Internet (offline)?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, installation, offline

I have Internet connection in my  home and I can install the latest version of `TypeScript` with this command: `npm install -g typescript` , But unfortunately There is no Internet at my work place (in fact we are not allowed to use Internet).

Beside this I googled But It seems  There is no *offline installer* for `Typescript`. My question is  how  can I handle this problem ?

I am totally new to `npm` and a step by step workaround would be appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an ugly solution: do `npm install` at home and copy the content of your globally installed packages [folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages) to work.

If you want to be able to do `npm install` without access to the internet you will need to configure your own [npm registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry) in your local network.

Comment: could you please elaborate your answer ? You mean only  copying and pasting the Target folder that you mentioned is enough ? for example should I apply any registry settings too or not ? ...

Comment: I think you don't need. For example in windows 10 if you copy paste your entire C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm I believe it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Sinopia](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinopia) in the past when working offline. It works as a cache for npm allowing you to work off-line provided you have installed the required packages while having an internet connection.

As per https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinopia#installation you can install and configure Sinopia with the following steps:

```
# installation and starting (application will create default
# config in config.yaml you can edit later)
$ npm install -g sinopia
$ sinopia

# npm configuration
$ npm set registry http://localhost:4873/

# if you use HTTPS, add an appropriate CA information
# ("null" means get CA list from OS)
$ npm set ca null
```