# is it possible to share same node modules between multiple projects?

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules

As of now I am installing node modules every time for the new angular project. Is it possible to use one projects node modules to other project by configuring any file(like changing the path in any file so it can use that modules)?

Comment: No, and you wouldnt want to the `node_modules` are specifc to that project, it gets generated from the package.json of the individual project

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46470247/5043867

Comment: logically I would not but for learning purpose the same set of dependencies I required for the projects.

Comment: @PujanShah in the angular.json file of your project, you can update the value of 
        "$schema": to the relative path of the node module folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Angular 6, you can generate multiple application in a single Angular project.

https://angular.io/cli/generate#application-command

applications generated by Angular cli command stay in same workspace and share node_modules.

For example, if you want to generate app `my-project`:

```
ng generate application my-project
```

If its dependencies are not different from previous one, you can use `--skipInstall=true` option with `ng generate` command.

And `ng serve` it with `--project` option:

```
ng serve --project=my-project
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I tried and its working as expected. :)

Answer (score 2):

First off I was shocked to see that this is actually a thing that some people are doing - see: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/681

***However I would advise against it.***

The idea behind each project having its own node_modules folder (and package.json) is that each of your projects should specify its own dependencies (including specific versions) which is a good thing for stability, predictability, reproducibility, etc. of your various projects. Here's a pretty good write-up on the node dependency model: https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2016/08/24/understanding-the-npm-dependency-model/

Now if you're talking about a local module (that you created yourself), you can have a look at https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.html

Comment: basically it should be different only, but as I mentioned for learning purpose there are multiple tasks(application) and all are having the same dependencies then we can create multiple applications in single project.