# npm install seems to install LOADS of modules, more than I asked for

Tags: node.js

Node JS newbie here, I am testing the imgur node module from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imgur). I run

```
npm install imgur --save
```

and when I look in the relevant node_modules folder I see about 50 or 60 modules listed. Why so many!? Are all these required?

Also, If I start multiple projects (different folders on my machine), do I have to have all those modules in each of the relevant node_modules folders, or is there a way to have ONE node_modules folder that would serve all of my test projects (imgur in this case)?

Thanking you.

Comment: This is all of the dependencies of imgur. Imgur itself also gets dependencies. They are required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: **Why so many!?**

A: Because they are dependencies of imgur. Based on the doc here https://www.npmjs.com/package/imgur, it has 27 depedencies. Each of them will be in a seperated folder under node_modules

Q:  **Are all these required?**

A: Yes. They are dependencies for imgur to get running as expected

Q: **If I start multiple projects (different folders on my machine), do I have to have all those modules in each of the relevant node_modules folders, or is there a way to have ONE node_modules folder that would serve all of my test projects (imgur in this case)?**

A: Yes. Keeping node_modules separately for different project is a good practice. If you want to use only one source to find libraries. Use `npm install -g` command and set the `NODE_PATH` environment variable to the path, the modules can be found by your project. Check detail here: [Where does npm install packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages)

Hope it helps